# iOS: notification actions - remove "open" in options menu

Tags: ios, notifications

I've got notifications with some actions; now if there's only one action for a notification, it displays the "alert view" with a `dismiss` and an `options` button. When pressing the options, I get 'Open', 'My Action' and 'Close'.

How can I achieve to avoid the options menu and get 'Dismiss' and 'My Action' right from the beginning?

I'm talking about the alert that appears e.g. when you're on the iPhone home screen and you have selected alert style "Alerts" for "Alert Style When Unlocked"

I've got a local push notification with just one action defined. Now I would expect to get the notification on the Home Screen with "Close" on the left and my defined action on the right. But instead I get this one:

[image]

[image]

I would love to avoid the additional step of tapping "Options" and then only get one real option.

The code I'm using:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (localNotif == nil) {
    return;
}

localNotif.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:NOTIFICATION_DELAY];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = text;

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNotif.category = ERROR_CATEGORY;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

registering for push notifications:

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *callSupportAction = [self actionWithIdentifier:@"callSupportAction" title:NSLocalizedString(@"callSupportActionTitle", @"") background:YES destructive:NO authenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *errorCategory = [self categoryWithIdentifier:ERROR_CATEGORY actions:@[callSupportAction]];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:errorCategory, nil];

UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];



- (UIMutableUserNotificationAction *)actionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier title:(NSString *)title background:(BOOL)background destructive:(BOOL)destructive authenticationRequired:(BOOL)authenticationRequired {
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    action.identifier = identifier;
    action.title = title;
    action.activationMode = background ? UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground : UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
    action.destructive = destructive;
    action.authenticationRequired = authenticationRequired;
    return action;
}

- (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *)categoryWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier actions:(NSArray *)actions {
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *category = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    category.identifier = identifier;

    if (actions.count > 2) {
        [category setActions:actions forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
        [category setActions:[actions subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];
    } else {
        [category setActions:actions forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    }
    return category;
}
```

Comment: please see my edit, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Are you talking about Remote notification ?

Comment: @swalkner Sorry, still unclear. Please post images of the problem.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to make the local notification.

Comment: Another comment request. Could you show us the code for `categoryWithIdentifier`

Comment: Can you try using the minimal context for all cases and see if that gets you what you are looking for? Not in front of my Mac to try it myself, but minimal should only present two options in the form of buttons.